Decide for which values of $p \in [1, +\infty]$ the following statement holds.
Problem: Let $L^p(\mu)$ be the space of equivalence classes of functions $f$ defined on the unit circle and measurable with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\mu$, such that
$$
\|f\|_p = \left(\int_{\mathbb{T}} \quad |f|^p \, d\mu \right)^{1/p} < + \infty.
$$
Decide for which values of $p \in [1, +\infty]$ the following statement holds:
"If $E$ is a non-empty, closed, and convex subset of $L^p(\mu)$, then there exists a unique $f_0 \in E$ such that $\|f_0\|_p \leq \|f\|_p$ for all $f \in E$."
Proof:
Consider the different cases:

For $p \in (1, \infty)$.
The real function $ t \longmapsto |t|^p $ is strictly convex, meaning that for any $ t_0, t_1 \in \mathbb{R} $ with $ t_0 \neq t_1 $, we have
$$
|\lambda t_0 + (1 - \lambda) t_1|^p < \lambda |t_0|^p + (1 - \lambda) |t_1|^p \quad \forall \lambda \in (0, 1).
$$


Let $ E $ be a closed, convex subset of $ L^p(\mu) $ and let $ m = \inf_{f \in E} \|f\|_p $. This is well-defined since $E$ is non-empty.
a) Existence of the minimum:
By the definition of infimum, we can construct a sequence $ \{f_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \subset E $ such that
$$
\|f_n\|_p < m + \frac{1}{n} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Since $ \{f_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} $ is bounded $( \|f_n\|_p \leq 2 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} )$ and $ E $ is closed, it follows from the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem that there exists a convergent subsequence $ \{f_{n_k}\}_{k = 1}^{\infty} $. For simplicity, rename this subsequence $ f_n $ and let $ f_0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n $. By Fatou's Lemma,
$$
\|f_0\|_p \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \|f_n\|_p = m,
$$
thus $ \|f_n\|_p = m $ and $ f_0 \in E $ since $ E $ is closed.
b) Uniqueness:
Assume $ \exists f, g \in E $ such that $ \|f\|_p = \|g\|_p = m $ and $ f \neq g $.
Since $ E $ is convex, $ (\lambda f + (1 - \lambda) g) \in E \quad \forall \lambda \in (0, 1) $. Using the convexity of $ t \longmapsto |t|^p $, we get
\begin{align*}
m^p &= \|\lambda f + (1 - \lambda) g\|_p^p = \int_{\mathbb{T}} \quad |\lambda f + (1 - \lambda) g|^p \, d\mu < \int_{\mathbb{T}} \left( \lambda |f|^p + (1 - \lambda) |g|^p \right) \, d\mu \\
&= \lambda \|f\|_p^p + (1 - \lambda) \|g\|_p^p = \lambda m^p + (1 - \lambda) m^p = m^p,
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction.

For $ p = 1 $.

Let $ E = \{f \in L^1(\mu) : \|f\|_1 = 1 \text{ and } f(t) \geq 0 \text{ a.e. } \mathbb{T}\} $.
$ E $ is convex since if $f, g \in E $, it is clear that $ \lambda f + (1 - \lambda) g \geq 0 $ a.e. and
\begin{align*}
\|\lambda f + (1 - \lambda) g\|_1 &= \int_{\mathbb{T}} \quad |\lambda f + (1 - \lambda) g | \, d\mu \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{T}} \left( \lambda f + (1 - \lambda) g \right) \, d\mu \\
&= \lambda \|f\|_1 + (1 - \lambda) \|g\|_1 = \lambda + (1 - \lambda) = 1.
\end{align*}
Let $ f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} $ and $ g(t) = \frac{1}{\pi} \mathcal{X}_{[0, \pi]}(t) $. Clearly, $ \|f\|_1 = \|g\|_1 = 1 $ and $ 1 = \inf_{f \in E} \|f\| $, but $ f \neq g $.

For $ p = \infty $.

Consider
$$
E = \{f \in L^{\infty}(\mu) : f(t) = 1 \text{ a.e. } t \in [0, \pi) \text{ and } f(t) \in [-1, 1] \text{ a.e. } t \in [\pi, 2 \pi)\}.
$$
Clearly, $ \|f\|_{\infty} = 1 \quad \forall f \in E $. For any $ \lambda \in (0, 1) $, we have $ \lambda f(t) + (1 - \lambda) g(t) = 1 $ a.e. $ t \in [0, \pi) $ and $ (\lambda f(t) + (1 - \lambda) g(t)) \in [-1, 1] $ a.e. $ t \in [\pi, 2\pi) $, so $ E $ is convex. However, $ f(t) = 1 $ and $ g(t) = \mathcal{X}_{[0, \pi)}(t) $ satisfy
$$
\|f\|_{\infty} = \|g\|_{\infty} = \inf_{h \in E} \|h\|_{\infty} = 1,
$$
but $f \neq g $.
Therefore, the statement is only true for $ p \in (1, \infty) $.

What's the question?

is it correct the solution I have given?

Well, I take $\lambda \in (0,1)$ instead of $\lambda \in [0,1]$ to have a strict inequality at the beginning. But I do not know exactly if that influences in the part of $p=1$ and $p=\infty$. @SineoftheTime

Furthermore, I would like to know if it is a correct and consistent demonstration in its entirety. I see it as correct, obviously, but I may have missed something important.

For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplication.

How exactly are you using the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem? Normally it applies to sequences of numbers, not functions.

See this generalization to strictly convex reflexive spaces

There is a crucial mistake in part a) of existence. You claim that since $f_n$ is bounded in $L^p$ it admits a norm convergent subsequence. Unfortunately this is false (in fact, it holds only in finite dimensional spaces). However, $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$ is a reflexive space and thus we can find a weakly convergent subsequence $(f_{k_n})$ of $(f_n)$. Denoting by  $f$ the weak limit of $  f_{k_n}$ and using  the lower semicontinuity of the norm with respect to the weak topology you get that
$$ \|f\|_p \le \liminf_n \|f_{k_n}\|_p \le m $$
and so $\|f\|_p = m$.  You can see more details in my previous answer.
Uniqueness in b) is almost correct. You need to replace

\begin{align*}
    m^p &= \|\lambda f + (1 - \lambda) g\|_p^p = \dots 
\end{align*}

by
\begin{align*}
    m^p & \le  \|\lambda f + (1 - \lambda) g\|_p^p = \dots 
\end{align*}
You also need to verify that the set $E$ is your counterexamples is closed, but this is rather easy.

I have posted a new solution correcting the mistakes you have told me. Could you take a look, please?

Problem Statement: We want to determine for which values of $ p \in [1, \infty] $ the following statement holds for $ L^p(\mu) $:

If $ E \subset L^p(\mu) $ is a non-empty, closed, and convex subset, then there exists a unique $ f_0 \in E $ such that $ \|f_0\|_p \leq \|f\|_p $ for all $ f \in E $.

Solution: The correct solution hinges on two key points:

Existence of an element of minimal norm in $ E $ for all $ p $ in the range $ 1 < p < \infty $, which relies on reflexivity.
Uniqueness of the element of minimal norm in $ E $, which requires both reflexivity and strict convexity.

Corrected Solution:
A. For $ p \in (1, \infty) $
In this case, $ L^p(\mu) $ is reflexive and strictly convex. We proceed with two parts: existence and uniqueness.
a) Existence of a Minimizer
Since $ E \subset L^p(\mu) $ is closed, convex, and non-empty, the infimum $ m = \inf_{f \in E} \|f\|_p $ is well-defined and finite. We aim to show that there exists an $ f_0 \in E $ such that $ \|f_0\|_p = m $.

Let $ \{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset E $ be a sequence such that $ \|f_n\|_p \to m $ as $ n \to \infty $. This sequence is bounded since $ \|f_n\|_p \leq m + 1 $ for large $ n $.
By reflexivity of $ L^p $ for $ 1 < p < \infty $, there exists a weakly convergent subsequence $ \{f_{n_k}\} \subset \{f_n\} $ with $ f_{n_k} \rightharpoonup f_0 $ weakly in $ L^p $ for some $ f_0 \in L^p $.
Since $ E $ is convex and closed, it is also weakly closed (by Mazur's theorem). Hence, $ f_0 \in E $.
By the weak lower semicontinuity of the $L^p $ norm, we have
$$ 
   \|f_0\|_p \leq \liminf_{k \to \infty} \|f_{n_k}\|_p = m.
   $$
Thus, $ \|f_0\|_p = m $, showing that $ f_0 $ is a minimizer in $ E $.

b) Uniqueness of the Minimizer
To establish uniqueness, assume there exist two distinct minimizers $ f_1, f_2 \in E $ such that $ \|f_1\|_p = \|f_2\|_p = m $.

Since $ E $ is convex, any convex combination $ \lambda f_1 + (1 - \lambda) f_2 \in E $ for $ \lambda \in (0,1) $.
Using the strict convexity of the $ L^p $ norm for $ 1 < p < \infty $, we get
$$
   \|\lambda f_1 + (1 - \lambda) f_2\|_p < \lambda \|f_1\|_p + (1 - \lambda) \|f_2\|_p = m.
   $$
This contradicts the minimality of $ m $, so no such distinct minimizers can exist. Thus, the minimizer is unique.

Therefore, for $ p \in (1, \infty) $, a unique minimizer exists in $ E $.
B. For $ p = 1 $
For $ L^1(\mu) $, reflexivity fails, which means weak convergence arguments cannot be applied to ensure the existence of a norm-minimizing element in a general closed convex subset $ E \subset L^1(\mu) $. We provide a counterexample to show that the statement does not hold in general for $ p = 1 $:

Let $ E = \{f \in L^1(\mu) : \|f\|_1 = 1, f \geq 0 \text{ a.e.}\} $.
Consider two distinct functions $ f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} $ and $ g(t) = \frac{1}{\pi} \chi_{[0, \pi]}(t) $, both of which belong to $ E $ and satisfy $ \|f\|_1 = \|g\|_1 = 1 $.
Here, $ \inf_{f \in E} \|f\|_1 = 1 $, but both $ f $ and $ g $ achieve this infimum, showing that the minimizer is not unique.

Thus, the statement does not hold for $ p = 1 $.
C. For $ p = \infty $
For $ L^\infty(\mu) $, strict convexity also fails, preventing uniqueness of minimizers.

Consider the set $ E = \{f \in L^\infty(\mu) : f(t) = 1 \text{ for } t \in [0, \pi), f(t) \in [-1, 1] \text{ for } t \in [\pi, 2\pi)\} $.
For any $ f \in E $, we have $ \|f\|_\infty = 1 $, and different choices of $ f $ in $ E $ give distinct functions with the same $ L^\infty $-norm.

Thus, uniqueness does not hold for $ p = \infty $ either.
Conclusion:
The statement holds if and only if $ p \in (1, \infty) $. This range ensures that $ L^p(\mu) $ is both reflexive and strictly convex, guaranteeing the existence and uniqueness of a norm-minimizing element in any closed, convex subset of $ L^p(\mu) $.

This looks good.
